# Cut delimiter works in terminal and not script

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

`cut -d$'\n' -f5 /home/me/Documents/file.txt`

This works perfectly fine when ran in the terminal and returns the fifth line of the file.
But in a script

```
AWKED=`cut -d$'\n' -f5 /home/me/Documents/file.txt`
```

gives this output

> cut: the delimiter must be a single character
>
> Try 'cut --help' for more information.

Why does it behave differently from when it's ran directly in the terminal?

**Edit:**

I have also tried using < and moreover I tried

`awked=$(cat /home/me/Documents/file.txt | cut -d$'\n' -f5)`

which similarly works fine in the terminal but not in a script, giving the same error as before.

**Edit 2:**

output of `grep -i awked script.sh | od -c`

```
0000000   a   w   k   e   d   =   $   (   c   u   t       -   d   $   '
0000020   \   n   '       -   f   5       /   h   o   m   e   /   m   e
0000040   /   D   o   c   u   m   e   n   t   s   /   f   i   l   e   .
0000060   t   x   t   )  \n
0000065
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line of original script was `#!/bin/sh` and changing to `#!/bin/bash` fixed the issue. As Gilles Quenot said, `$'\n'` is a bashism. So, it is not interpreted by dash, which sh links to by default.

Comment: Should belongs to a comment

Comment: Explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash You can list available shells this way in terminal: cat /etc/shells

Answer (score 2):

## The solution is to use the `<` redirection and to use the shebang `#!/bin/bash`:

```
AWKED=`cut -d$'\n' -f5 < /home/me/Documents/file.txt`
```

## But

- UPPER CASE variables are reserved for system use
- The backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

## So finally:

```
#!/bin/bash

awked=$(cut -d $'\n' -f5 < /home/me/Documents/file.txt)
```

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested but I get the same output as before.

Comment: Output != error, is it error or output ?

Comment: I said it's the same as before.



    cut: the delimiter must be a single character

    Try 'cut --help' for more information.

Comment: Edited post, try again (refresh the page)

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: Like I said, the very first command I wrote in my question works as intended in the terminal. The only difference is that it's being ran from a bash script and that causes some issue.

Comment: What is the output of `grep -i awked script.sh | od -c` ?

Comment: See edit 2-----

Comment: **You don't have `<` character in edit2**

Comment: That makes no difference. It gives the same error either way.

Comment: Try this: `wget https://pastebin.com/raw/hZ68ert6 -O script.sh; bash script.sh` Works as it should

Comment: I should have said so, but the first line in my script was #!/bin/sh

and after changing that to #!/bin/bash it works. I didn't realize that could make a difference, or think of changing that until I looked at your script. It must be a quirk of sh. My bad I didn't mention earlier.

Comment: @M__ You called it `a quirk of sh` but "quirk" is not a good word here. [`sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html) is relatively basic on purpose, so sh scripts work reliably in limited systems. "Big" shells support more features and take more resources, these shells are not always available. You used `$'\n'` which is a [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism).

Comment: @GillesQuenot "UPPER CASE variables are reserved for system use."  No they are not. At best it is a convention used by many shell script writers.